# Formula Help - Crystal Reports Cross Tab

Tags: crystal-reports, pivot-table

Can anyone give me the idea, how to add summary at the red highlighted in the images.

Preview Mode

[image: 1]

Design View

[image: 2]

Comment: Is there a data field you can group the data on so that each group contains only the rows you need to summarize?

Comment: @R.McMillan It has two row groups, Row Group #1 and Row Group #2.
Since it is a cross tab, we don't have exclusive groups on report canvas.